# Lucky Numbers in Python

Tags: python, numbers, sieve

For who's interested in; lucky numbers are generated by eliminating numbers based on their position in the set. i.e:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
```

First eliminates every second number bc second value is 2:

```
1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21
```

First remaining number in the list after 1 is 3; so it eliminates every third number:

```
1,3,7,9,13,15,17,19,21
```

Next number is 7; eliminate every 7th number in the list:

```
1,3,7,9,13,15,21
```

Next surviving nunmber after 7 is 9 but obviously there are not enough numbers to eliminate.
For further information you can check [Lucky Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number)

So, if my list doesn't contain any negative number and begins with 1 i.e:

```
    numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22']
```

My code supposed to delete every number unless it's a lucky number, so I tried:

```
    def lucky_numbers(numbers):
        del numbers[::-2]   # Delete even numbers
        while int(numbers[1]) < len(numbers):
            x = int(numbers[1])
            del numbers[-1::x]
            print(numbers)
            return
        return
    lucky_numbers(numbers)
```

But it returns:

```
['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '15', '17', '19']
```

Where am I wrong? Or is there any efficient way to write it? Thank you.

Comment: `1,3,7,9,13,15,17,19,21`  isn't the second number still 3? so shouldn't it delete every 3rd element again?

Comment: It proceeds to the next remaining number. "Continues removing the nth remaining numbers, where n is the next number in the list after the last surviving number". So it's like 2nd, 3rd, 7th, 9th, 13th...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative index is a bit confusing to me (at least), see if this code is easy to interpret-

```py
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22']

def lucky_numbers(numbers):
    index = 1
    next_freq = int(numbers[index])
    while int(next_freq) < len(numbers):
        del numbers[next_freq-1::next_freq]
        print(numbers)
        if str(next_freq) in numbers:
            index += 1
            next_freq = int(numbers[index])
        else:
            next_freq = int(numbers[index])
    return


lucky_numbers(numbers)
```

```
['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '15', '17', '19', '21']
['1', '3', '7', '9', '13', '15', '19', '21']
['1', '3', '7', '9', '13', '15', '21']
```

Comment: Okay I see my fault now. Apprarently I was overthinking on it. Thank you so much, appreciate it.